# Creating relationship between primary key to composite key -- phpMyAdmin

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, relational-database

I am trying to create a relation between a field 'fldEmpID' in my Employees table to a foreign composite key which consists of fldEmpID and fldEventID but it is not allowing the relation to be created. I don't understand why this relation won't work, I was able to create a similar relation between fldEventID from an Events to the composite key. Both fldEmpID fields in each table are int(11). What can I do to create this relation?

The following are the two tables... (I would like to keep the composite key on the table to the right as it helps to prevent duplicates and works well)

[image]

Comment: When creating foreign key relationships, both sides of the relationship must have the same number of columns and data types must match. No exceptions. You can create the relationship using the fldEmpID in both tables.

Comment: Can you show us your structure for both tables and describe briefly how you're trying to create the relationship?

Comment: @IsaacBennetch sorry I'm just getting this up, but I edited my post to include the tables. I essentially brought up phpMyAdmin and used the visual relation diagram and attempted to set fldEmpID on the left as the reference key and then fldEmpID on the right as the foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to work as expected for me. I created the tables and used the Designer tab to create the relation (by selecting the "Create relation" icon, then clicking fldEmpId in table a, and finally selecting fldEmpID in table b).

For reference, I pasted below the structure of my table (which includes the keys and restraints)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `a` (
  `fldEmpId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fldEmpName` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fldEmail` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fldPassHash` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fldPassSalt` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `fldAdmin` enum('1','2') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `b` (
  `fldEmpID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fldEventID` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `fldDTAdded` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fldDTRemoved` datetime NOT NULL,
  `fldPosition` enum('0','1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

ALTER TABLE `a`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`fldEmpId`);

ALTER TABLE `b`
 ADD PRIMARY KEY (`fldEmpID`), ADD UNIQUE KEY `fldEventID` (`fldEventID`);

ALTER TABLE `a`
MODIFY `fldEmpId` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `b`
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk` FOREIGN KEY (`fldEmpID`) REFERENCES `a` (`fldEmpId`);
```